# How can I use pattern to validate my html input

Tags: html

so I was trying to validate my html input so that it would only allow characters to be entered with a minimum length of 4 characters and I was using pattern="([a-zA-Z]+).{3,}" because I thought it would only allow upper and lower case letters with a length of at least 4 but it only checks the first letter. I'm quite new to regex stuff so any help would be appreciated.

edit: changed the min length validation to just use minlength

edit: found the fix I was being stupid and it just needed ^ in ^[a-zA-Z]+

```html
 <!-- One-attribute-per-line for readability -->

 <input
    class     = "govuk-input"
    id        = "name"
    name      = "name"
    type      = "text"
    pattern   = "([a-zA-Z]+)"
    title     = "Must be atleast 4 characters long, max length of 50 and may only contain characters from A-Z or a-z"
    maxlength = "50"
    minlength = "3"
    required
/>
```

Comment: To build and test regex, visit this website https://regex101.com/

Comment: why not just use a `minlength` for your min length validation and the pattern for your alphabet validation (ie separate them out into 2 different validations, like you have with your maxlength)

Comment: I noticed `"{{job_family_name}}"` so this is an input for a person's name? If so **you're doing it wrong**: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: ah yeah that actually isn't supposed to be there, working through git and someone had pushed it up with that and I just asked them. Thanks for pointing that out